# MS Access Report for multiple queries

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a report in access that shows sales forecast in 3 subreports (the next 30 days, 31-60 days and 61-90 days). I haven't been able to figure out how to create a report like that. I have 3 queries for each date range. I would like to group the data for each salesperson showing company, amount and date. Something like below.

Can I do it using subforms or is there a better way? Thanks.

```
 30 days 
 Bob Smith
          Acme      $3000     10/31/2019
          Detla     $2000     11/12/2019 
 60 days 
 Julie Brown
          Bigly     $4000     12/05/2019 
 90 days 
 Bob Smith
          Acme      $2500     01/10/2020 
 Julie Brown
          Bigly     $3300     01/12/2020
```

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea to me. Three queries and three subreports. Each subreport with Sorting & Grouping settings. Why can't you figure it out? Exactly what issue have you encountered?

Comment: too broad,  please add a description of the query results you are starting with so we can reproduce the problem.  otherwise the broad answer is yes sub-reports will work.